# Collection of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a list of items and I want to display a total for the selected items.
The list of items is diplayed twice so if I check some item in the first list is checked also the same item in the second list. 
The problem is that it doesn't calculates the sum (it displays Nan).

```js
function Item(id, name, price) {
  this.id = id;
  this.name = name;
  this.price = price;
}

var listOfItems = [
  new Item(1, 'item1', 25),
  new Item(2, 'item2', 30),
  new Item(3, 'item3', 50)
];

function viewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.items = ko.observableArray(listOfItems);
  self.selectedItem = ko.observableArray();

  self.Total = ko.computed(function() {
    var count = 0;
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.selectedItem(), function(r) {
      count += r.price;
    });
    return count;
  });
};
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" value="" data-bind="checkedValue: id, checked: $parent.selectedItem"><span data-bind="text: name"></span>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" value="" data-bind="checkedValue: id, checked: $parent.selectedItem"><span data-bind="text: name"></span>
  </li>
</ul>

<div data-bind="text:Total"></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried logging `r`. Its an integer and not an object

Comment: Not sure. Do you want to see the second duplicate checklist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've modified your sample:

```js
function Item(id, name, price) {
  this.id = id;
  this.name = name;
  this.price = price;
  this.checked = ko.observable(false);
}

var listOfItems = [
  new Item(1, 'item1', 25),
  new Item(2, 'item2', 30),
  new Item(3, 'item3', 50)
];

function viewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.items = ko.observableArray(listOfItems);

  self.Total = ko.computed(function() {
    //return self.items().filter(function(item) { return item.checked(); }).length;
    return self.items().reduce(function(sum, item) { return item.checked() ? sum + item.price : sum; }, 0);
  });
};
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" value="" data-bind="checkedValue: id, checked: checked"><span data-bind="text: name"></span>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" value="" data-bind="checkedValue: id, checked: checked"><span data-bind="text: name"></span>
  </li>
</ul>

<div data-bind="text:Total"></div>
```

Comment: Hi I dont want to count checked. I want to find Total of checked

Answer (score 1):

As I have already commented, `r` in `r.price` is an integer and not an object. Hence you are getting `NaN`. Try using `count += r` instead. Following code depicts the same.

```js
function Item(id, name, price) {
  this.id = id;
  this.name = name;
  this.price = price;
}

var listOfItems = [
  new Item(1, 'item1', 25),
  new Item(2, 'item2', 30),
  new Item(3, 'item3', 50)
];

function viewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.items = ko.observableArray(listOfItems);
  self.selectedItem = ko.observableArray();

  self.Total = ko.computed(function() {
    var count = 0;
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.selectedItem(), function(r) {
      console.log(r)
      count += r;
    });
    return count;
  });
};
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" value="" data-bind="checkedValue: id, checked: $parent.selectedItem"><span data-bind="text: name"></span>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" value="" data-bind="checkedValue: id, checked: $parent.selectedItem"><span data-bind="text: name"></span>
  </li>
</ul>

<div data-bind="text:Total"></div>
```